# Automatically only link source with included header in CMake (simple project structure)

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following simple c++ project structure:

- `include/` contains header files
- `src/` contains the source files
- `cli/` contains source files with a main method

Currently, I build the whole source into a single static library and then compile each file in `cli/` individually and link that static library. I do this with just one `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory that basically looks like this:

```
include_directories(include)

set(HEADERS
  include/file1.hpp
  include/file2.hpp
  include/sub1/file3.hpp
  include/sub2/file4.hpp
  )

set(SOURCE_FILES
  src/file1.cpp
  src/file2.cpp
  src/sub1/file3.cpp
  src/sub2/file4.cpp
  )

set(EXECUTABLE_FILES
  cli/app1.cpp
  cli/app2.cpp
  cli/app3.cpp
  )

add_library(code STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADERS})

foreach (file ${EXECUTABLE_FILES})
    get_filename_component(executable ${file} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${executable} ${file})
    target_link_libraries(${executable} code)
endforeach ()
```

When I add a new file, I just add it to the appropriate list of files (headers, source, or executable).

- **Advantage:** Simple work-flow with little overhead for maintaining the `CMakeLists.txt`.
- **Disadvantage:** For each executable, the one big library is linked, even if the executable only uses the stuff in one of the source files (right now, there are about 15 executables using different subsets of the 25 source files).

**My Question: Can I fix the disadvantage while keeping the advantage?**

The only solution for fixing the disadvantage I could find is to manually specify for each executable which source files it needs. This is too tedious and error prone for my use case, as I will certainly forget to update the dependencies.

This is a bit unsatisfactory, as there is a very simple rule to which sources need to be linked: Every source file has a corresponding header file and I need to link `src/file.cpp` if and only if `include/file.hpp` is included. Is there any good way to tell CMake about this rule? Or do I need to write my own script that generates the CMakeLists.txt (which feels a bit like writing my own build system, which I would like to avoid)?

Comment: Why is it an issue if every executable links to the library? If it's a shared library wouldn't it save space when either way?

Comment: As for the STATIC library which is built from several sources, created library actually consisted from the several objects. When link an executable with such library, modern linkers are able to drop objects if they are not used by the executable.

Comment: I think by default the linker will only link necessary objects into the executable. In fact you need to add `--whole-archive` (gcc) or `/OPT:NOREF` (msvc) to linker options if you want to preserve the whole big static library.

Comment: I was under the impression that linking everything increases executable size (which it apparently does not) and that it slows down compilation (the linker has to be called for all executables on every change).

Comment: So the proper way to use CMake here is to just link everything (just as I currently do)?